# Should i put the URL of my rss feed in my sitemap

Tags: xml, rss, sitemap

Was wondering if anyone put the URL of their rss feed in their site's sitemap.xml file, and if so what was the reasoning?

The only thing I could think of is that google might not want to crawl/ index the rss file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will likely find your url and index it (as well as the links from it) by itself if you've setup discovery (put `<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://...">` in the `<head>` part of the HTML).

Comment: So I am assuming that you put that snippet on example.com/blog and it would look something like this `<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom-xml" title="example.com" href="http://www.example.com/rss.xml">`